# how to write program which multiply element in array with next element and give the output as array

Tags: python, arrays

I have one array with `n` elements and I want to obtain a new array(`newArr`) which is given by multiplying it by next element i.e

```
arr = [1,2,3,5,7,11,17,23,...]
newArr = [2,6,15,35,77,187,...]
```

i.e.

```
newArr = [1*2, 2*3, 3*5, 5*7, 7*11, 11*17,...]
```

I tried:

```
def prime_num(n):
a = []
for num in range(2,n):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if(num%i==0):
            break
        else:
            print(num)
    a.append(num)
    #print(a)
    return(a[i]*a[i+1])
```

I want `a` to be an array similar to `newArr` shown above but it is only printing one number that is total multiplication. How can I obtain `newArr`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` this way:

```
arr = [1,2,3,5,7,11,17,23]

newarr = [x*y for x, y in zip(arr, arr[1:])]
# [2, 6, 15, 35, 77, 187, 391]
```